How to proof any NCCR gives a weakly crepant categorical resolution in dimension 3?
Background
Let $R$ be a Gorenstein normal domain of dimension 3. An NCCR of $R$ is an endomorphism ring $\Lambda=\text{End}_R(M)$ of a reflexive module $M$ such that $\Lambda$ is CM over $R$ and has finite global dimension.
Let $\Lambda$ be an NCCR of $R$. Consider the functors $\pi^* = M\otimes^L_R-\colon \text{Perf}(R)\to D^b(\Lambda)$ and $\pi_* = \text{RHom}_\Lambda(M, -)\colon D^b(\Lambda)\to\text{Perf}(R)$. We say the NCCR $\Lambda$ gives a weakly crepant resolution of $R$ if and only if the following are satisfied:
(1) $\pi^*$ is left adjoint to $\pi_*$.
(2) The natural transformation $\text{id}_\text{Perf(R)}\Rightarrow \pi^*\pi_*$ is an isomorphism.
(3) $\pi^*$ is also right adjoint to $\pi_*$.
In his ICM 2022 lecture note [1, before Proposition 2.15], van den Bergh makes the following claim (which he says follows from Proposition 2.15 that yields that $\text{Ext}^i_\Lambda(M,M)=0$ for $i>0$):
Claim: $\Lambda$ always gives a strongly (and therefore weakly) categorical resolution.
My Attempt
I'm trying to write down a solid proof of the claim, but have failed to show (3). Here's my attempt.
(1) is just the derived hom-tensor adjunction, and (2) uses Proposition 2.15: For $X\in D^b(\Lambda)$, we have
$$\text{RHom}_\Lambda(M, M\otimes^L_R X)\cong \text{RHom}_\Lambda(M, M)\otimes^L_R X\cong \text{Hom}_\Lambda(M, M)\otimes^L_R X\cong X.$$
For (3), it is required to show that
$$\text{RHom}_\Lambda(Y, M\otimes^L_R X)\cong \text{RHom}_R(\text{RHom}_\Lambda (M, Y), X), \text{for } X\in\text{Perf}(R) \text{ and } Y\in D^b(\Lambda).$$
I can show (3) under addition assumptions that $M\in \text{CM}(R)$ and that $M$ is a generator as an $R$-module. In this situation, $M$ is a projective $\Lambda$-module, and therefore we have $\text{Hom}_R(M, R)\cong \text{Hom}_\Lambda(M, \Lambda)$. Now since $M$ is CM over the Gorenstein ring $R$, we have
$$\text{RHom}_R(\text{RHom}_\Lambda(M, \Lambda), R)=\text{RHom}_R(\text{Hom}_R(M, R), R)=0.$$
However we don't have these assumptions now, and the only condition we haven't used is that $\Lambda$ is a CM as an $R$-module. I have no idea how it might be applied to yield (3).
Any comments are welcome! Thank you.
[1] Van den Bergh, Michel(B-VUB-NDM),
Noncommutative crepant resolutions, an overview. ICM—International Congress of Mathematicians. Vol. 2. Plenary lectures, 1354–1391.
EMS Press, Berlin, [2023], ©2023.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.09703.
